# Better way to say "cover our a***s"

Tags: phrase-requests, offensive-language, minced-oaths

I'm looking for a couple of good coined phrases that I can use in front of business people, apologies if the one I had in mind offends anyone.

I'd use "can sleep at night" but I want the phrase to imply legal liability if we don't do something.

Comment: protect our interests

Comment: Please just don't use "due diligence" in any way, shape, or form!

Comment: You need to be careful what you say. If making a business proposal requires you to raise the subject of protection from legal liability, that issue may well become the primary focus of the meeting, instead of whatever your project was really supposed to be about. Unless, of course, your business plan is predicated on exploiting some "legal loophole".

Comment: Thanks guys, the end result is basically: "... please keep it in the back of your head, that as we get closer to D-Day we might get a tester in for a couple of days to bug bash this.... Since it’s a major project, I feel this is a good measure to cover one's bases in order to avoid any appearance of impropriety and to adhere to compliance, risk management, damage control and above all protecting our reputation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To bring in the legal aspect I might say one of: 
"*to ensure we are on solid legal ground*", or "*have solid legal standing*", 
or "*to ensure we have the law on our side*".

Also, "*to cover one's bases*" is a politically correct version of your original "*a***s*".

Answer (score 4):

A metaphorical phrase might be **Safety Net**. Or, by analogy, **Insurance**. Insurance costs us money, and there is no benefit unless and until a bad thing happens and we have to claim. We incur the cost because we want to minimise the consequences should the bad thing happen.

More literally and technically, perhaps words and phrases like **Compliance**, **Obligation**, **Risk Management**, **Damage Control** or **Protect Our Reputation**.

Answer (score 2):

A phrase which pertains to the same use is *cover all angles,* alluding to resolving a problem, completing a project according to some specification or similar circumstance, from the viewpoints of all concerned parties.

Answer (score 1):

To weakly imply legal obligation I would say:

"To avoid any **appearance of impropriety**."

Answer (score 1):

*Cover your **assets*** is very close and non-offensive.

Comment: You use this, if you are an artist - e.g., - as in:

We need to cover our arts-assets to ensure they are free from plagiarism and original artwork.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying to business people is:

**Do due diligence.**

Source:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_diligence