# What’s a non-vulgar alternative for “covering one’s ***”?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, offensive-language, phrase-requests

Oxford Dictionaries Online writes in their U.S. section
that the phase [*cover one’s ass*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/cover_one's_ass) is 
an **informal** phrase meaning:

> Foresee and avoid the possibility of attack or criticism.
>
> - *‘I like to cover my ass when I make big generalizations’*

And if you [search for that same phrase in their general dictionary covering World English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cover_one's_back), you’ll notice that they mention how *cover one’s ass* is
specifically a North American expression.

The Wikipedia page for [Cover your ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass) says:

> The phrase *cover your ass* is **generally viewed as a vulgar term**, often
>   replaced by the less-vulgar sounding initials *CYA*. Safire identified *CYA* as
>   a synecdoche, in the same sense that the word “ass” had come to reference
>   the whole person.

The [entry for *cover someone’s ass* in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cover_someone%27s_ass) states begins:

> 1. (*Canada, US, idiomatic*) To make preparations or take precautions to 
>      ensure that a person is not blamed or punished for his or her conduct.

*Collins English Dictionary* says in [its entry for the phrase](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cover-ones-ass) that:

> ***slang***, mainly US and Canadian
>   to take such action as one considers necessary to avoid censure, ridicule, 
>   etc at a later time

While dictionary-dot-com’s page for [cover one’s ass](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cover-one-s-ass) mentions (but only
in their example citations, not their definition section): that some call
it *risk management*

> To provide or arrange for exculpation; devise excuses and alibis:
>
> - *Some call it “**risk management**,” others “covering your ass.”*
> - *The FBI may have to let you be destroyed to cover its own ass.*
> - *CYA, you know, that old French expression that means making sure 
>     that when historians write about it all it won’t be seen as happening on
>     your shift.*
>
> > <sub>credited to *The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition* 
> >     by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, Ph.D.; 
> >     Copyright (C) 2007 by HarperCollins Publishers.</sub>

*Risk management* is a nice little phrase, but 
what other ***non-vulgar expressions*** are there that means the same thing as *covering one’s ass* means, but without being considered **vulgar**?

Comment: There are (at least) three different variations on the meaning of CYA.  One is to meet the letter of the law, to avoid future legal problems.  A second is to exhaustively cover all possibilities (eg, in a test or review).  Or one might take preemptory  steps (such as spin doctoring or creating a diversion) to divert attention.  The "synonym" you choose is apt to be sensitive to what sense is being used.

Comment: You can just use ***make sure you’re covered***

Comment: Does "I've got your back" count?

Answer (score 8):

> **[cover one's back](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cover_one%27s_back)**
>   Foresee and avoid the possibility of attack or criticism.
>   ‘never take chances, always cover your back’

Oxford Dictionaries

In legalese, the expression **[risk mitigation](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/risk-mitigation.html)** is heard

> A systematic reduction in the extent of exposure to a risk and/or the likelihood of its occurrence. Also called **risk reduction**.
>   <sup>Business Dictionary</sup>

To **bulletproof your contract** aka *a rock solid contract*  aka *[Terms and Conditions](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/terms-and-conditions)*

[Source](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/191778): *Bulletproof Terms for Every Contract*

> **If you bulletproof something**, you make it resistant to failure.
>   *We have to bulletproof this program before we let the users at it; check every input, catch every possible flaw … it must not fail in use.* 
>   [Wiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/bulletproof)

Comment: In Britain "cover your back" would be standard, whereas "cover your arse" would be unusual and appear vulgar. Therefore if Americans wish an alternative to "cover your ass" this suggestion would seem the nearest. In a figurative or antique sense, it is what is behind you (and you cannot see) that you need to beware of, not particularly your buttocks.

Answer (score 4):

**Hedge**

> (hedge, v., def 2)
>   limit or qualify something by conditions or exceptions. *Experts usually hedge their predictions, just in case*

*Oxford American Dictionary*

Answer (score 3):

Covering your *backside*, *rear* or other synonym for *ass* is widely understood. Even just *covering yourself* is an option.

The basic phrase is rather mild really - only just vulgar but certainly informal. It's the informality that often means an alternative is needed. Again *cover yourself (against...)* is useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could get quite creative with this one, depending how euphemistic you want to be:

Risk management is up the euphemistic end - others might be spin doctoring, PR (public relations), reputation management or protecting your assets.

Less euphemistic terms might be: dodging the rap, diverting blame, teflon coating, defensive strategising, acting the innocent, denying wrongdoing etc.

Answer (score 3):

In a situation of risk, where blame is very easily attributed, I find it best to foresee worst case scenarios and to '**minimise repercussions'**.

Just for background, I have been in the Security business for just over twenty years and this aspect of my work - planning for the worst that can happen - is just about the most important, both for the safety of others and for my own.

That said, we are very vulnerable, blame lands first at our door if things go badly wrong, so in order to keep contracts and customers we constantly minimise future problems to absolute zero, if at all possible.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_scenario) :

A worst-case scenario is a concept in **risk management** wherein the planner, in planning for potential disasters, considers the **most severe possible outcome** that can reasonably be projected to occur in a given situation, Conceiving of worst-case scenarios is a common form of strategic planning, specifically scenario planning, **to prepare for and minimize contingencies** that could result in accidents, quality problems, or other issues.

Answer (score 3):

First, the phrase is a verb and object; "risk management" is not. Any replacement should be substitutable for "cover your ass".

"Minimize repercussions" fits the bill, but it would be closer to say, I think, "avoid repercussions". Or better: "protect yourself from possible repercussions".

CYA often has a connotation of excessive attention to avoiding repercussions. "Cover your tracks" might be a substitute if the goal is to hide something.

Example:
- You payed cash instead of using a credit card for the hotel room with your lover to cover your ass
- You payed cash [...] to cover your tracks.

A verbose substitute might be "take measures to avoid questions and to prepare to defend your motives or results if questioned".

I guess I like "protect yourself from possible repercussions" best.

Comment: Thanks for justly pointing out that "risk management" is not a suitable alternative because it's a noun not a verb. I also appreciate that you’ve written more than a from-the-hip one-liner which isn't just a bunch of dictionary copypasta with no reasoning of one’s own, the way SWRs so often draw. If you have a chance to tidy this up a bit, I believe that you’ve written *payed* for what in standard English is normally written *paid* in these situations. You may also wish to include asome citations and references illustrating and supporting your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

While CYA somehow has rather negative connotations,  conjuring up images of selfishness, incompetence and evasion of responsibility, there are a number of common expressions using 'cover'  that can be used more positively in the context of risk management to refer to **good planning** in terms of anticipating many possible outcomes including potential risks and extraordinary events:

**Cover all the angles**

Usually means 'to prepare for every possibility'. Random examples:

> Starting a new business during a recession certainly carries many risks, but Tom is confident that he has *covered all the angles.*
>
> Alice and Bob have tried to *cover all the angles* while strengthening their relationship.

This link gives a few more examples:

https://ludwig.guru/s/cover+all+the+angles

**Cover all the bases**

> To account for or provide a way to address every possible outcome, scenario, contingency, etc.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+all+the+bases

**Contingency planning**

> A contingency plan is a plan devised for an outcome other than in the usual (expected) plan. It is often used for risk management when an exceptional risk that, though unlikely, would have catastrophic consequences.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_plan

Expressions involving 'defence' which often have sporting or military origins can also be used to refer to good preparation for negative outcomes:

**Tight defensive game**

**Well organised defence**

**Watertight defence.**

> Tom's long experience in unstable financial markets taught him to  first protect his new company with a *watertight defence.*

---

**Update:** google search later led me to this exact duplicate of your question asked in 2012 right here on English.SE, which has many good suggestions to fit your case including 'cover all angles':

[Better way to say "cover our a***s"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62512/better-way-to-say-cover-our-as)

Comment: You know you leave me with no choice but to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Now that OP has so many good options from *both* questions it may be OK @Mari-lou A. I think "cover your back" which you suggested is very much the closest polite alternative to CYA, especially since some anatomical definitions of 'back' refer to the entire posterior part of the body of a person in the standing position.

Comment: Off you go, do the right thing and vote to close the question as being a duplicate.

Comment: Don't you know I never vote to close @Mari-lou A? Please don't debate the matter -- I was well worked over for that reason by more than one member on IPS.SE! I am not at all particular that this question should be closed even if it is obviously a duplicate of the earlier question. More pedantic or conscientious users than you or I can do the deed here on English.SE

Comment: So to clarify, you don't believe any question is off-topic, or if a question has been asked three or four times already it should always remain open.

Comment: This is the debate I wish to avoid @Mari-lou A. I believe every question should remain open unless it is obviously off topic such as a computer science question asked by mistake on English.SE -- if there is the slightest doubt leave it open, I say. And there are so many members who believe in strictly closing questions that my personal opinion against casting close votes certainly does not hurt enforcement of policy on a site like ELU.

Comment: tchrist beat me to it.